# R: cumulatively multiply rows of df in a list and return a list from the operation

Tags: r

I have a list of factor, and an initial base number (i.e. 100), would like to multiply the base with the factor 1 to fill the first factored position, and then be able to use the first position and multiply it by factor position 2, output it, and multiply the result with factor 3, output accordingly. please see sample data and code below for details.

Sample Data:

```
base <- 100

myList3 <- list()
myList3[[1]]<- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,1,1,1,2,3,1,0.9,0.8), nrow=3, ncol=3))
myList3[[2]]<- as.data.frame(matrix(c(2,2,2,1,2,3,1,0.8,0.7), nrow=3, ncol=3))
myList3[[3]]<- as.data.frame(matrix(c(3,3,3,1,2,3,1,0.8,0.9), nrow=3, ncol=3))
colnames <- c("path","month", "factor")
factor<-lapply(myList3, setNames,colnames)
print(factor)
```

```
> print(factor)
[[1]]
  path month factor
1    1     1    1.0
2    1     2    0.9
3    1     3    0.8

[[2]]
  path month factor
1    2     1    1.0
2    2     2    0.8
3    2     3    0.7

[[3]]
  path month factor
1    3     1    1.0
2    3     2    0.8
3    3     3    0.9
```

Tried to write a function, not working

```
Function <- function(x,y) {
  for (k in 2:100){
    x[1,3] <- base
    x[k,3] <- x[k-1,3]*y[k,3]
  }
  return(x)
}

x <- lapply(Function,x,y)
```

Desired Output:

```
myList3 <- list()
myList3[[1]]<- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,1,1,1,2,3,100,90,72), nrow=3, ncol=3))
myList3[[2]]<- as.data.frame(matrix(c(2,2,2,1,2,3,100,80,56), nrow=3, ncol=3))
myList3[[3]]<- as.data.frame(matrix(c(3,3,3,1,2,3,100,80,72), nrow=3, ncol=3))
colnames <- c("path","month", "data")
data<-lapply(myList3, setNames,colnames)
print(data)
```

```
> print(data)
[[1]]
  path month data
1    1     1  100
2    1     2   90
3    1     3   72

[[2]]
  path month data
1    2     1  100
2    2     2   80
3    2     3   56

[[3]]
  path month data
1    3     1  100
2    3     2   80
3    3     3   72
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `transform` with `cumprod`

```
lapply(factor, transform, factor = cumprod(factor) * 100)
#[[1]]
#  path month factor
#1    1     1    100
#2    1     2     90
#3    1     3     72

#[[2]]
#  path month factor
#1    2     1    100
#2    2     2     80
#3    2     3     56

#[[3]]
#  path month factor
#1    3     1    100
#2    3     2     80
#3    3     3     72
```

Or another option is `Reduce` with `*`

```
lapply(factor, transform, factor = 100 * Reduce(`*`, factor, accumulate = TRUE))
```

---

The `tidyverse` option would be

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(factor, ~ .x %>%
                  mutate(factor = cumprod(factor) * 100))
```

NOTE: It is better not to name object names or column names with function names (`factor` is a function)

Comment: great point, I didn't actually use the name "factor" in my the actual code (just too lazy to come up another name I guess), but appreciate your suggestion and answer, it worked great.